# How can I cause Grails/GORM to use default sequence values in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grails, orm, grails-orm

When I define a domain object like:

```
class MusicPlayed {

  String user
  Date date = new Date()
  String mood

  static mapping = {
    id name: 'played_id'
    version false
  }

}
```

I get a postgres sequence automatically defined like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_music_played
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

That's great -- but I'd love to have this become the default value for my `id` field. In other words, I'd like to have the table defined with:

```
    played_id bigint DEFAULT nextval('seq_music_played'::regclass) NOT NULL,
```

... but this doesn't happen. So when my client code requires manual SQL invocation, I'm stuck pulling new values form the sequence instead of just relying on auto-population.

Is there any way to cause this table to be created "the way I want," or do I need to forgo gorm's table-creation magic and just create the tables myself with a db-creation script that runs at install-time?

---

**Note** My question is similar to [How to set up an insert to a grails created file with next sequence number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822623/how-to-set-up-an-insert-to-a-grails-created-file-with-next-sequence-number), but I'm specifically looking for a solution that doesn't pollute my client code.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :-)

```
 static mapping = {
    id generator: 'native', params: [sequence: 'my_seq'], defaultValue: "nextval('my_seq')"
 }
```

Generating something like:

```
create table author (
    id int8 default nextval('nsl_global_seq') not null,...
```

for postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
    static mapping = {
     id generator: 'native', params:[sequence:'your_seq']
    }
```

Additionally, i would update the DEFAULT-Value of the id-column via

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('your_seq');
```

This is extremely useful for manual INSERTs

UPDATE - use [liquibase](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) for the default-column-problem:

```
changeSet(author:'Bosh', id:'your_table_seq_defaults', failOnError: true) {
sql ("ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('your_seq')")
}
```

Comment: +1 for the liquibase reference -- I didn't know the syntax was this lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to create my tables directly in PostgreSQL and then map them in grails.

I took the best idea to the sequences-generated-IDs from here:

http://blog.wolfman.com/articles/2009/11/11/using-postgresql-with-grails

Give it a try and then smile at your former problems :)

rawi

Comment: so GORM uses it's own generator, which isn't consistent

Answer (score -2):

You can define it in Config.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    id generator: 'sequence'
}
```

Comment: this doesn't take into account his sequence-name 'seq_music_played'